# How to BZ2Decompress file containing multiple files?

Tags: python, bz2

I'm trying to unzip a zipfile (compressed with BZ2) into a directory.
The zipfile contains multiple files.

All (and I've seen quite a few already...) of the examples show how to decompress the zipfile into one file.

This is what I have so far:

```py
def unzipBzip2(passed_targetDir, passed_zipfile):
    full_zipfile = pathlib.Path(constants.APP.ROOT, constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, passed_zipfile)
    full_target = pathlib.Path(constants.APP.ROOT, constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, passed_targetDir)
    
    with open(file=full_zipfile, mode="rb") as zipfile, open(full_target, 'wb') as target:
        decompressor = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()

        for data in iter(lambda : zipfile.read(100*1024), b''):
            target.write(decompressor.decompress(data))

    return
```

Error is:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... (stack) ...
  File "/Users/bert/Project/unzipBzip2.py", line 26, in unzipBzip2
    with open(file=fullzipfile, mode="rb") as zipfile, open(full_target, 'wb') as target:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/bert/Project/data/51fba56e-c598-491a-a5e4-57373a59367a'
```

Well, "/Users/bert/Project/data/51fba56e-c598-491a-a5e4-57373a59367a" is indeed a directory. And that's what it should be, since the unzipped files (from the BZ2 zipfile) should be written in that directory.

**Why does decompressor complain that this is a directory?**

If I change the target to a file

```
    full_target = pathlib.Path(constants.APP.ROOT, constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, passed_targetDir, 'x.x')
```

it gives the following error:

```sh
  File "/Users/bert/Project/unzipBzip2.py", line 30, in unzipBzip2
    target.write(decompressor.decompress(data))
OSError: Invalid data stream
```

Comment: I think you are confusing zip archives which contain one or more member files and [BZ2}(https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html) which is just a way to compress a single file — it's not a container of other files like the former.

Comment: what's the extension of your zipfile? `tar.bz2` ?

Comment: @emptyhua, don't mind the extension. It's *.bzip2.zip. That confused me. It now appears to be a 7z zipfile. And that one does have more than one file in it.  However the Python package py7zr does not recognise it, while the linux command (7z) does.

Comment: If you could post a (small) sample file somewhere, I may be able help write code to recognize and decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

If your zipfile is a bz2 compressed zip, the code below should work.

```py
def unzipBzip2(passed_targetDir, passed_zipfile):
    full_zipfile = pathlib.Path(constants.APP.ROOT, constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, passed_zipfile)
    full_target = pathlib.Path(constants.APP.ROOT, constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER, passed_targetDir)

    with open(file=full_zipfile, mode="rb") as rawf:
        with bz2.BZ2File(rawf) as bz2f:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(bz2f) as zipf:
                zipf.extractall(full_target)
```

You could try to  use `file` command to identify archive format. for example your file is `abc.unkown.bz2`

```
$ file ./abc.unkown.bz2
./abc.unkown.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k
```

now we can decompress it using bzip2, and got `abc.unkown`

```
$ bzip2 -d ./abc.unkown.bz2
```

then continue with de decompressed `abc.unkown`

```
$ file ./abc.unkown
./abc.unkown: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

the example file is `zip` format inside bz2

Comment: Even when there are more than one file in the bz2? Does that mean that bz2 is not only for one-file-compression but for more files?

Comment: bz2 can only compress one file. there 's another archive format inside bz2 to support multi files. eg: tar.bz2 tar file compressed in bz2 .  you need to confirm what's the format compressed in your bz2 file?

Comment: The **tar** file format is not "inside" `bz2`, it's a yet another (rather ancient) standalone [computer archive file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) — which could be `bx2` compressed like any other single file.

Comment: @martineau i updated my answer, it may help to identify the archive format.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement. The OP will still need to determine the type of data in the uncompressed file *programmatically* to determine whether to use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) or [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#module-tarfile) module in the standard library to extract the files from a Zip archive or tarball, as appropriate.